# ADXL345 reading issue

Tags: embedded

I am interfacing ADXL345 with SAMC21 for SPI communication and try to read DEVICEID at 4 MHZ but it need to read data atleast 5 times to get proper output why is not get in single attempt.
      if I don't include for loop in following code it will not getting DEVICEID.

void SPI_read(uint32_t address)
{

```
PORT->Group[0].OUTCLR.reg=1<<CS;
volatile uint32_t temp=0;
for(char i=5;i>0;i--)
{

    while(SERCOM1->SPI.INTFLAG.bit.DRE==0);
    SERCOM1->SPI.DATA.reg=(0x80|address);        /* for read operation*/

    while(SERCOM1->SPI.INTFLAG.bit.RXC==0);

    temp=SERCOM1->SPI.DATA.reg;
}
PORT->Group[0].OUTSET.reg=1<<CS;
```

}

Comment: What else do you read instead? Garbage, zeroes, ones? Is it the same every time? Do you always need 5 tries to read the correct value or sometimes less, sometimes more? Did you consider the boot/initialization time of the ADXL345? Also you should post your hardware layout, it would help to identify any noise issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,whenever I read Device_ID I get correct output but when try to read two memory locations back to back it will not give correct result without for loop but when I add for loop it will give correct output. minimum 5 itterations required for ADXL345